# JWT Auth vs Session Auth for API

Tags: api, session, jwt

I'm developing an API that requires some authenticating functions.

I usually use the session method: User posts to login API and I return a session ID. Then, for all the others API calls, the user needs to attach that session ID.

My supervisor suggests that I use JWT for this kind of job. But I can't seem to find any remarkable pros of using JWT over the above session method. There's even a huge con in case I want to maintain some kind of "session data" when using JWT.

Do you have any idea about the pros of using JWT in this case? Should I migrate the old code to JWT?

Comment: I am asking myself the same question. Did you ever reach a conclusion ?

Comment: Not worthy, I keep using the session right now, and thanks for the provided article, marked it as correct now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually came upon this article which kind of covers the whole topic, and thus answers the question :

http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

> Stateless JWT tokens cannot be invalidated or updated, and will
>   introduce either size issues or security issues depending on where you
>   store them. Stateful JWT tokens are functionally the same as session
>   cookies, but without the battle-tested and well-reviewed
>   implementations or client support.
>
> Unless you work on a Reddit-scale application, there's no reason to be
>   using JWT tokens as a session mechanism. Just use sessions.

Comment: Whether JWT tokens can or cannot be invalidated is a implementation detail (store a session ID in the token if you must).  It eliminates one of the benefits of the technology partially (saving a DB round trip) but it doesn't invalidate the technology.